# blur event is not working for knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dom-events

Scenario is that when we enter something in a textbox and put mouse anywhere on the page there should be an alert.
Tried with following fiddler code.

Can anybody please correct the following code?

Note- I am not using `hasfocus` so please do not tell me to use it rather please suggest how I can use `blur` method.

http://jsfiddle.net/bipin_pandey/2vc8X/1/

```
<input id="textbox" type="text" data-bind="event: { blur: blurFunction() }" />


var model = (function () {
    var self = {};
    self.blurFunction=ko.observable();
    self.blurFunction = blurmethod();
    function blurmethod() {
            alert('we are here - onblur');
    }    
    
    
    return self;
})();



ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Comment: Where is your fiddle ?

Comment: Updated it now. sorry just a bit late :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the braces `()` from `blurmethod` when your assigning it to your View-Model `blurFunction`. WHy? becuase in your code your are executing the function not passing it as a parameter. And no need either for braces `()` in your View.

[***Working Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/2vc8X/2/)